# Applying Edgar Codd’s 1NF normalization procedure

Tags: database-design, relational-database, normalization

In 1970, Edgar Codd published his landmark paper [‘A Relational Model of Data for Large Shared Data Banks’](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/%7Ezives/03f/cis550/codd.pdf) where he defined relational databases as well as their normalization to first normal form (1NF) in section 1.4, page 381. It is a procedure for eliminating *non-simple* domains (domains whose elements are relations) from a set of relation schemata (i.e. a database schema) in order to allow simple two-dimensional array representations without pointers.

[image: First normal form.]

I have applied this 1NF normalization procedure to the following six database schemata modeling music recordings.

Italics denotes a key constraint.

*R*<sub>1</sub> > *R*<sub>2</sub> denotes a non-simple domain relationships such that the relation schema *R*<sub>1</sub> has an attribute *R*<sub>2</sub> whose domain constraint is described by the relation schema *R*<sub>2</sub> (i.e. it is a relation-valued domain). For instance in Codd’s example, we have the following non-simple domain relationships: `employee` > `jobhistory` > `salaryhistory` and `employee` > `children`.

### Database schema 1

Unnormalized (non-simple domain relationships: `artist` > `album` > `song`):

- artist(*artist_id*, artist_name, album);
- album(*album_id*, album_title, album_date, song);
- song (*song_id*, song_title).

Normalized (1NF):

- artist(*artist_id*, artist_name);
- album(*artist_id*, *album_id*, album_title, album_date);
- song(*artist_id*, *album_id*, *song_id*, song_title).

### Database schema 2

Unnormalized (non-simple domain relationships: `artist` > `song` > `album`):

- artist(*artist_id*, artist_name, song);
- song(*song_id*, song_title, album);
- album(*album_id*, album_title, album_date).

Normalized (1NF):

- artist(*artist_id*, artist_name);
- song(*artist_id*, *song_id*, song_title);
- album(*artist_id*, *song_id*, *album_id*, album_title, album_date).

### Database schema 3

Unnormalized (non-simple domain relationships: `album` > `artist` > `song`):

- album(*album_id*, album_title, album_date, artist);
- artist(*artist_id*, artist_name, song);
- song(*song_id*, song_title).

Normalized (1NF):

- album(*album_id*, album_title, album_date);
- artist(*album_id*, *artist_id*, artist_name);
- song(*album_id*, *artist_id*, *song_id*, song_title).

### Database schema 4

Unnormalized (non-simple domain relationships: `album` > `song` > `artist`):

- album(*album_id*, album_title, album_date, song);
- song(*song_id*, song_title, artist);
- artist(*artist_id*, artist_name).

Normalized (1NF):

- album(*album_id*, album_title, album_date);
- song(*album_id*, *song_id*, song_title);
- artist(*album_id*, *song_id*, *artist_id*, artist_name).

### Database schema 5

Unnormalized (non-simple domain relationships: `song` > `artist` > `album`):

- song(*song_id*, song_title, artist);
- artist(*artist_id*, artist_name, album);
- album(*album_id*, album_title, album_date).

Normalized (1NF):

- song(*song_id*, song_title);
- artist(*song_id*, *artist_id*, artist_name);
- album(*song_id*, *artist_id*, *album_id*, album_title, album_date).

### Database schema 6

Unnormalized (non-simple domain relationships: `song` > `album` > `artist`):

- song(*song_id*, song_title, album);
- album(*album_id*, album_title, album_date, artist);
- artist(*artist_id*, artist_name).

Normalized (1NF):

- song(*song_id*, song_title);
- album(*song_id*, *album_id*, album_title, album_date);
- artist(*song_id*, *album_id*, *artist_id*, artist_name).

**Which of these six normalized database schemata makes more sense?**

Comment: It's a more complicated model  than either of these options embodies.  An artist can appear on many albums and record many songs, either by themselves or in cooperation with other artists.    See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)

Answer (score 9):

Both need some further normalization work if you want a fully normalized model.

However, it is either missing the notion of M:N relationship (first-class relationships), or it is insufficiently normalized, such that modeling an M:N relationship requires duplication, which makes it denormalized.

To get to further normalized database, we would model both entities and relationships using their own tables.

```
artist (artist_id, artist_name)
album (album_id, album_title, album_date)
song (song_id, song_title, song_duration)

songs_x_album (song_id, album_id)
artists_x_song (artist_id, song_id)
```

The first three are simple entity tables, and, the latter two are relationship tables, capturing the relationships without duplicating any other info from albums, artists, or songs.

`artists_x_album` can be derived from the above using a larger join.

Of course, due to the nature of relational queries, given a relationship table we can traverse an M:N relationship `a_x_b` bidirectionally from an `a` to its `b`s and also from a `b` to its `a`s.

---

In some but not all cases relationship tables need their own id; not shown in the above (there are only foreign keys).

---

There is a lot more to consider, of course. Authoring a song and performing/publishing a song are potentially different, for example. Songs are sometimes released without an album.

Comment: Thanks for this interesting answer. There seems to be several [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) levels. In the 1970 paper that I quoted, Codd only describes the first normal form (1NF). This is the one I used. He described the second normal form (2NF) and third normal form (3NF) in a 1971 paper. Unfortunately I do not have access to it. Do you? Which normal form does your further normalization belong to?

Comment: Also could you elaborate on why my variant 2 is closer to a normalized data model?

Comment: Good question.  On second look I don't believe either is more normalized, so I take that part back.

Comment: @Maggyero, it is a 1NF normalisation (and due to the structure of the unnormalized data, it is trivially also 2NF and 3NF)

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Thanks. Could you explain why it is 2NF and 3NF?

Comment: @Maggyero, 2NF: All non-key fields depend on the entire key (trivial, as there are no tables with multi-field composite keys *and* non-key fields); 3NF: All field values depend *only* on the key, there is no correlation between non-key field values that must be maintained (also trivial in this case).

Comment: In Codd’s example above, is the relation between employees and their children one-to-many or many-to-many?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau In Codd’s example above, is the relation between employees and their children one-to-many or many-to-many?

Comment: @Maggyero, it appears to be a one-to-many relation (each child belongs to one employee; employees that are a couple and have children together are not considered in the model and in the era when this article was written that could have been a valid solution).

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau What makes you say that couples are not considered? Why would two records with the same `childname` attribute but different `man#` attributes in the `children` relation schema *always* denote two different children?

Comment: @Maggyero, The model depicted in Codd's example will treat different records in the `children` schema as different children as there is no indication anywhere that the `childname` attribute needs to be globally unique. And if it is not globally unique, then you just cannot tell if two records with the `childname` attribute value "Bart" refer to the same child or not and the only safe assumption that you can make is that they are different children.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau But why do we need unique references in the first place? Is aliasing forbidden in the relational model? Do you use a UUID key in all your relations?

Comment: @Maggyero, suppose the records show there are 5 employees with a child called 'Bart'. The records do not show if any of those employees are in a relationship with each other. How many children (real persons) do those records refer to

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau But not all models require this piece of information, do they?

Comment: @Maggyero, not all models need the information but you also cannot make assumptions about information that is not part of the model.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau [This answer’s](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/292680/87954) author seems to disagree.

Answer (score 6):

You are missing a couple components in your model that represent the relationships between your artists, songs, and albums. These are sometimes referred to as [associative tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity).

1. Albums have numbered tracks, each of which is a song.
2. Artists can be credited with multiple songs.

So a normalized model might look like the following. Your basic tables:

```
artist (artist_id, artist_name)
song (song_id, song_name)
album (album_id, album_name)
```

And your associative tables:

```
album_track (album_id, song_id, track_number)
artist_credit (artist_id, song_id)
```

The associative tables embody the [many-to-many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)) relationships that others have pointed out.

Note that for some types of music, the above may not be enough. For example, for some kinds of electronic dance music, there is an artist credit for the album but not for the songs (e.g. a DJ who put together the album but did not write any of the songs). For that you might need three associative tables instead of two:

```
album_track (album_id, song_id, track_number)
song_artist_credit (artist_id, song_id)
album_artist_credit (artist_id, album_id)
```

And in addition maybe you want to keep track of what role each artist had in a song, e.g. if they sung or wrote or played the bongos. For that you would add a role attribute to the artist credit table for songs and a [domain table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_domain):

```
album_track (album_id, song_id, track_number)
song_artist_credit (artist_id, song_id, role_id)
album_artist_credit (artist_id, album_id)
credit_role (role_id, role_name)
```

These are just the basics. There is a lot more complexity in the music industry, and you would have to decide how much to build into your model. To give you an idea, I would recommend you review the work of someone who has already dealt with this, e.g. take a look at the [Spotify object model](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/object-model/).

Comment: Thanks for the Spotify link and the insightful remark on my album lacking an artist and my song lacking a track number. Regarding the extra associative relations `album_track` and `artist_credit`, I am not sure they are necessary since my normalized relations already have their domains.

Comment: Is the `credit_role` relation necessary? I would have removed it and replace the attributes `(artist_id, song_id, role_id)` of the relation `song_artist_credit` with `(artist_id, song_id, role_name)`.

Comment: Consider a query where you are obtaining the list of songs where Madonna was the songwriter. How would you do that with `role_name`? You'd have to make sure that the names are used consistently and spelled the same way. Also, you wouldn't be able to fit as many keys into a data page (since a name is longer than an ID) which would increase total I/O. If you're okay with both of those, then it's not necessary.

Comment: Ah okay, in other words your `credit_role` relation is a kind of enumeration type?

Comment: Exactly. It is a list of valid values. In SQL, we refer to this as a "Domain table."

Comment: It's real world, therefore more complicated. For example, I have one song appearing on two albums of two different artists. And that's ignoring "Best of... " collections duplicating songs from the same artist. I know of one person who is two entirely different artists (with the same last name). There are US and UK versions of albums with very slight but real differences. And so on and so on.

Comment: @gnasher729 "For example, I have one song appearing on two albums of two different artists. And that's ignoring "Best of... " collections duplicating songs from the same artist." John Wu’s data model or mine allow many-to-many relationships between songs and albums so I don’t think this is a problem. "There are US and UK versions of albums with very slight but real differences." Excellent remark, albums have several different versions like standard/deluxe, country specific, reissues (e.g. remastered), so rather than adding this in the `album_name` attribute an extra attribute could be useful.

Comment: In Codd’s example above, is the relation between employees and their children one-to-many or many-to-many?

Answer (score 2):

There are two questions which are actually separate:

1. What are the data and relationships you want to represent in the database.
2. How to represent this as normalized tables.

Your question is not really about normalization, it is about deciding on a data model. You present 6 different data models, and then the normalization of each. The normalizations seem correct given the data models, but most of the data models does not make sense.

(I assume in your notation ">" indicates a one-to-many relationship, i.e. "artist > album > song" means one artist to many albums and one album to many songs.)

Variant 1: One artist can have multiple albums and one album have multiple songs. The seem like a reasonable model, although it would not be able to express if multiple artists collaborated on the same album or song.

Variant 2: A song can occur on multiple albums BUT an album can only have one song. This is not a very useful model!

Variant 3: An album can have multiple artists BUT an artist can only have one album.

Variant 4: A song can have multiple artists BUT an artist can only have one song!

Variant 5: A song can have multiple artists and an artist can have multiple albums BUT again there can only be one song per album.

Variant 6: A song can occur on multiple albums and an album can have multiple artists BUT an album can have only one song.

Of these 6 variants, only variant 1 would be reasonably useful, if a bit simplistic.

The problem with the rest of the variants is you really need many-to-many relationships if you want to express more information. If you want to represent an album having multiple artists, then you also need to represent that an artist can have multiple albums. So you need a many-to-many relationship between artists and albums.

You might be missing this in the analysis, because Codd's example does not have any many-to-many relationships, all the connections are one-to-many.

This might not be immediately obvious to a modern reader, since the connections in his diagram (fig 3a) does not have the cardinality (one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-many etc.) explicitly stated as we probably would today. But the context of the example is a hierarchical database which only support one-to-many relationships. In any case, the ambiguity is resolved in the normalized form (fig 3b) where it is clear that there is a one-to-many relationship between employee' and children'.

It might seem weird that his data model does not consider that two employees could have a child together. Maybe it is a payroll database where the number of children might be important for benefits, but whether two employees shared the same child would be irrelevant. Or maybe he just didn't consider the possibility. In any case this is just an example.

For the music recordings database you also have to decide on a data model. Be aware that there is no "correct" data model for a given domain. A data model is always a simplified view of reality and depends on the requirements on your database and application.

Can an album have multiple artists? Can a song have multiple artists? Can an album have songs which are not by the same artist as the album artists? If a song occur on multiple albums is this the "same" song? These are "business" decisions which depends on the purpose of the database. A record shop might need to decide on a single artist per record in order to organize the records alphabetically per artist. A digital music library does not have such a constraint and might instead record artists per song rather than album. Should you include producers, song writers, session musicians etc? It all depends on the business requirements of the database.

Assuming a simple model where an album only have a single artist and all songs on the album by the same artist, the model presented as variant 1 would be sufficient.

A more fine-grained model where each song can have multiple artists might look like this:

```
Album -(one to many)-> Song <-(many to many)-> Artist
```

And this would be a normalized representation:

```
Artist: (artist_ID(PK), artist_name)

Album: (album_ID(PK), album_title, album_date)

Song: (song_id(PK), album_ID(FK), song_title)

Artist_Song: (song_ID(FK), artist_ID(FK))
```

(I prefer synthetic priary keys (artist_ID, album_ID etc.) because there could be multiple artist with the same name, multiple albums with the same title and so on.)

You should clarify what data model you want to represent before starting to normalize.

Comment: Why are you avoiding composite keys (by excluding the foreign keys of the parent relations from the keys)?

Comment: In Codd’s example above, is the relation between employees and their children one-to-many or many-to-many?

Comment: @Maggyero: In Codds example there is a one-to-many relationship from employee to children.

Comment: What makes you say that couples are not considered? Why would two records with the same `childname` attribute but different `man#` attributes in the `children` relation schema *always* denote two different children?

Comment: @Maggyero: You have that backwards - if a couple have a child, the child have to be registered twice (one for each man#) so two different records does *not* always represent two different children.

Comment: I know that a couple’s child will be registered in two different records, hence my question, since you stated that two different records sharing the same `childname` always represent two different children when you said that the relation is one-to-many. You see the contradiction?

Comment: @Maggyero: One-to-many refers to the relationships expressed in the data model. A child record can only refer to a single employee through its `#man` attribute. In the real world a child can obviously have more than one parent, but in the data model Codd represent, a child can only have one parent. So you have to distinguish between the real wold and the simplified model you decide to represent in the database.

Comment: The relation employee–children is one-to-many means the relation does not have two records sharing the same child. E.g. {(1, ’Thomas’), (2, ‘Paul’), (2, ’Julia’)} is one-to-many, but {(1, ’Thomas’), (2, ‘Paul’), (2, ’Julia’), (3, ’Thomas’)} is not, it is many-to-many. So what makes you say that Codd’s example does not allow the second relation?

Comment: @Maggyero: In the data model Codd shows, a child is uniquely identified by the combination of `#man` and `childname`. So (1, ’Thomas’) and (3, ’Thomas’) would represent distinct children with different parents which just happen to have the same name. The data model does not support the notion of a child having multiple parents.

Comment: Since you are saying that the second relation is allowed, you acknowledge that the relation employees–children is many-to-many, not one-to-many. ‘In the data model Codd shows, a child is uniquely identified by the combination of #man and childname’ Where did you read this? A child *record* is uniquely identified by the combination of `#man` and `childname`, not a *real* child. The relation between a record and its referent is a different relation than the relation employees–children we are talking about.

Comment: @Maggyero: Again, the terms like "one-to-many" and "many-to-many" refer to what can be expressed in a given data model or schema. Since the data model shown does not allow a child to refer to multiple parents, it is one-to-many relationship from employee to child, not a many-to-many.

Comment: ‘Again, the terms like "one-to-many" and "many-to-many" refer to what can be expressed in a given data model or schema.’ No, these are unicity properties of a relation: a relation is one-to-many if it is injective and not functional, and many-to-many if it is not injective nor functional. ‘Since the data model shown does not allow a child to refer to multiple parents’ Could you provide a quote in Codd’s paper supporting this statement?

Comment: @Maggyero: The sentence "*Job history and children are non-simple domains of the relation employee*" means that one employee element can have multiple children and multiple job history elements. Quote: "*The terms attribute and repeating group in present data base terminology are roughly analogous to simple domain and nonsimple domain, respectively.*" But you can also see directly from the normalized form that there is no possible way a unique element of children could refer to more than one employee.

Comment: ‘means that one employee element can have multiple children and multiple job history elements.’ Yes it is the right-side ‘many’ in one-to-many or many-to-many, i.e. it means the relation does *not* have the functional property. Your quote says nothing on the left-side, i.e. the injective property, so you cannot claim it is also injective (one-to-many). ‘from the normalized form that there is no possible way an element of children could refer to more than one employee’ I disagree, the normalized relation schema `children` *does* allow the records (1, ’Thomas’, 2016) and (3, ’Thomas’, 2016).

Comment: @Maggyero: These are two different elements (given they have different values for the keys, and a key uniquely identifies an element). A many-to-many relationship is when a single element in table A can refer to multiple elements in table B *and* a single element in table B can refer to multiple elements in table A.

Comment: And that is exactly the case: a single element `man#` can refer to multiple elements `childname` (e.g. (2, ‘Paul’), (2, ’Julia’)) *and* a single element `childname` can refer to multiple elements `man#` (e.g. (1, ’Thomas’) and (3, ’Thomas’)). You finally got it.

Comment: @Maggyero: So you are saying there is a many-to-many relationship between child *names* and employees? This is true. But there is not a many-to-many between *children* and employees, since a child is a tuple (or row) in the children table, not just a name.

Comment: Yes I am saying the relationship between `man#` and `childname` is many-to-many, and since `man#` is the key of the unnormalized relation `employee` and `childname` is the key of the unnormalized relation `children`, there is also a many-to-many relationship between `employee` rows and `children` rows.

Comment: @Maggyero: The *un*normalized set (fig 3a) is the data model displayed in hierarchical form where the relationships are given by the tree graph rather than through attributes. In the normalizes form (fig 3b) the relationships are instead represented through foreign keys. (This is the major difference between hierarchical databases and relational databases. Hierarchical databases represent relationships through "links" while relational databases use data, e.g. foreign keys.) You can see in the normalized form there is no way that one row in 'children could refer to multiple rows in 'employee.

Comment: A foreign key in *one* tuple can *never* refer to two tuples in the foreign relation, by definition, so your definition of many-to-many is incorrect. However *two* tuples with the same attributes except the foreign key `man#` in the normalized relation `children′` can refer to two tuples in the normalized relation `employee′`, e.g. `(1, "Thomas", 2016-03-12)` and `(3, "Thomas", 2016-03-12)`.

Comment: @Maggyero: Two tuples referring to two other tuples is just a one-to-one relationship.  Many-to-many is implemented using a junction table with have foreign keys to two other tables. E.g. songs and artists could have a many-to-many relationship through a junction table which have foreign keys to both songs and artists tables. See the example with an Artist_Song table in the answer.

Comment: That is a great edit by the way which really tries to address my real questions (which I have poorly formulated), thanks Jacques.

Comment: ‘I assume in your notation ">" indicates a one-to-many relationship’ No, I should have used `—`, which is a symmetric symbol, to emphasize that I don’t assume any multiplicity on the relationship between the domains.

Comment: @Maggyero: So each relationship could be either one-to-one or one-to-many or many-to-many?

Comment: Yes, or many-to-one. I did not specify (like Codd).

Comment: @Maggyero: But your use of foreign keys in the normalized form does imply the multiplicity. For example in variant 1 you have artist_id on album which implies a foreign key from album to artist which in turn implies a one-to-many relationship from artist to album.

Comment: ‘It might seem weird that his data model does not consider that two employees could have a child together. Maybe it is a payroll database where **the number** of children might be important for benefits, but whether two employees shared the same child would be irrelevant.’ Yes, only the local identity/multiplicity (within the context of a given employee) of a child is relevant in this model, not his global identity/multiplicity. We don’t know his global identity/multiplicity, like one-to-many or many-to-many. Within a given parent, it is one-to-many, within the global namespace, we don’t know.

Comment: ‘I assume in your notation ">" indicates a one-to-many relationship’ No, but contrary to what I said previously an asymmetric symbol was necessary anyway to show the nesting direction of the relation schemata. `artist` > `album` > `song` means that the relation schema `artist` has an attribute `album` whose domain constraint is described by the relation schema `album` (i.e. a relation-valued domain), and that the relation schema `album` has an attribute `song` whose domain constraint is described by the relation schema `song` (i.e. a relation-valued domain).

Comment: @Maggyero: Thanks for the clarification. You should probably also indicate which attributes are keys, otherwise the schema is ambiguous. Codd indicate keys with italics.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I should have done that from the start. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

#### Understanding & Approach

You need to take the approach that this is an established paper, from 50 years ago, and try to understand it, as it is (as it was, fifty years ago).

- Note that the terms are dated
- Note that in fifty years, the academics and theoreticians who allege to serve this space, and write textbooks on the subject, have not articulated this.  They are stuck in their pre-1970 Record Filing Systems.

---

> In 1970, Edgar Codd published his landmark paper ‘A Relational Model of Data for Large Shared Data Banks’ where he defined relational databases as well as their normalization to first normal form (1NF) in section 1.4

No.

- That is not "1NF”.  Codd has not named it as such, and 1NF is already defined

  - **1NF**: the domain is Atomic, not divisible, wrt the platform
- If anything, that `Fig 3(b) Normalised Set` is the definition of **Relational Key Normal Form**,
- with the pre-requisite `Fig 3(a) Unnormalised Set` being the **Hierarchic Normal Form**.

Which unfortunately none of the academics and theoreticians have articulated, in fifty years of various textbooks and filth.

---

> It is a procedure for eliminating non-simple domains (domains whose elements are relations) of a collection of relations in order to allow a simple two-dimensional array representation without pointers.

No.

1. Codd uses the term *domain* no less than 83 times.  Without contradicting the core meaning, it does mean distinctly different things in different contexts.  Here *non-simple domain* means a repeating group or subordinate rows, which is deployed in a child relation.

2. The goal or purpose is not to "*allow a simple two-dimensional array representation without pointers*", that is simple enough to obtain via a `SELECT`, from any set of relations.  That is just a capability of the *Relational Model*, not a goal.

3. The goal at that point, is to demonstrate logical **Relational Keys**, and how to achieve them.
4. The overall goal of the *Relational Model* is to treat data logically, 100% logically, in all aspects of logic.*

   - Unfortunately those who write textbooks are blissfully stuck in the little that they can understand, which is the physical, so they **add** a physical frame with `RecordID`s.

---

> I have applied this normalization procedure to the following variants of collection of relations modeling music recordings.

No, you have not *applied that Normalisation procedure*.

- Codd requires that Keys are **made up from the data**, yours are not.
- You have `RecordIDs`, which are physical pointers, which are expressly prohibited.  Use of such additional fields will severely cripple the modelling exercise; complicate the coding; and degrade performance.
- Codd requires the pre-requisite Hierarchic NF, which means arranging the collection into **trees** (**D**irected **A**cyclic **G**raphs or DAGs), which you have not.  Instead of six possibles, give us one tree that is correct.
- Then perform Relational Key NF on that.

Yes, you have six variants.  No, you do not have one collection, you have six collections.

#### Variants

That is a completely separate question, regarding data modelling, using a given collection of data (not six), which are in bad shape.  You have not even specified which attributes you intend as Keys.  It has nothing at all to do with understanding Codd's paper, or understanding how to obtain Relational Key NF.  It is simply,

> *which of these six variants is best* ?

No criteria for choosing better or best is given, so it is a free-for-all with the responders trying to help, and no Answer is correct.

The attributes are not good, so you are better off collecting more relevant data, and asking a single data modelling question.

Another way of stating that is, your six variants are merely an attempt to understand:

- the **hierarchy** that Codd has given in **Fig 3(a)**,
- and his Normalisation **Fig 3(b)**
- using a collection of your own, and six possible combinations of such.
  Again, you are best advised to understand what Codd has given in his example, using his collection, first.

#### Codd’s *Relational Model*

You need to understand a bit more re your snapshot fragment of the *RM*.  Since you are asking questions about it, first I provide the file structure of the best-known HDBMS of the era, IBM's IMS.

- Note the single access key, the rest are physical pointers (red)
- The internal Keys prevent duplication of records (they were not rows) within the region.
  [image: Hierarchical DBMS • File Structure]

Now an explanation of Codd’s Fig 3(a).  Straight out of the Hierarchic Model, but perceived logically.

- Note the tree, it is horizontal
  [image: Relational Model Fig 3(a) • Unnormalised Set]

And now, an explanation of Codd’s Fig 3(b).

- Note the same tree, it is vertical.
  [image: Relational Model Fig 3(b) • Nnormalised Set]

#### Relational Data Model

If I cut to the chase, if I use data from the real world (ie. your six variants, normalised, plus relevant Identifying data), this is what the finished product would look like.  This is an example, as per your six variants, it is not a fully researched industry data model.
[image: Relational Data Model for Maggyero]

- there are three hierarchies: SongWriter; Producer; Artist
- notice the Relational Keys, which define the hierarchies

#### Note

- The Standard for Relational Data Modelling since 1983 is IDEF1X. For those unfamiliar with the Standard, refer to the short **[IDEF1X Introduction](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Documentary%20Examples/IDEF1X%20Introduction.pdf)**.

Comment: I admit that my question was a mess. Thanks for the clarifications and the great model. Shouldn’t an album also have zero or more artists, and one or more labels?

Comment: You should also have a producer per album track as it can be different for each track (e.g. [*The Lion King: Original Motion Picture Soundtrack*](https://musicbrainz.org/release/5f3d76cd-97dc-4f94-b757-acd911b6d36e)). Also the credited track artist or album artist is not always the performer, it can be the songwriter, so we may rename your relation Artist to Performer (e.g. [*The Lion King: Original Motion Picture Soundtrack*](https://musicbrainz.org/release/5f3d76cd-97dc-4f94-b757-acd911b6d36e)).

Comment: @Maggyero  Whoa.  That data model is just an example, from what I gleaned from your six variants.  It is not fully researched, to cater for the entire industry.  Eg. a song may be written by more than one SongWriter.  But sure, post the full requirement, and I will respond with a data model that fulfils it.

Comment: ‘Note the single key, the rest are physical pointers (red).’ So what prevents them for pointing to the same ‘Children Region’, i.e. two employees sharing the same children?

Comment: @Maggyero  1) Your question now leads into the physical structure of the IMS (HDBMS) file, and its limits.  Prevention was done by the HDBMS.  2) If two employees have the one child, the child record (not row) has to be duplicated.  One of the explicit goals that IBM gave Codd was to overcome that limitation.  Which he did, brilliantly (the *RM* does not duplicate such a child).  [Bill of Materials](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Student%20Resolutions/Bill%20of%20Materials.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the bill of materials problem, I was not aware that Codd was trying to solve it at IBM. ‘put another way, it resolves a many-to-many relation between rows in the same table’ Exactly, so why do people in this page claim that the relation between employee and children is one-to-many?

Comment: You said: ‘That is not "1NF”. Codd has not named it as such, and 1NF is already defined. 1NF: the domain is Atomic, not divisible, wrt the platform.’ Yet in his paper, p. 380, Codd said: ‘So far, we have discussed examples of relations which are defined on nonsimple domains—domain whose elements are atomic (nondecomposable) values. Nonatomic values can be discussed within the relation framework. Thus some domains may have relations as elements. These relations may, in turn, be defined on nonsimple domains, and so on.’ So I disagree, Codd did define 1NF in this paper.

Comment: ‘No, you have not applied that Normalisation procedure. Codd requires that Keys are made up from the data, yours are not. You have RecordIDs, which are physical pointers, which are expressly prohibited.  Use of such additional fields will severely cripple the modelling exercise; complicate the coding; and degrade performance.’ What does performance have to do with normalization? Using artificial keys or not is orthogonal to normalization. I did apply Codd normalization, I think you misread my question.

Comment: ’Codd requires the pre-requisite Hierarchic NF, which means arranging the collection into trees (Directed Acyclic Graphs or DAGs), which you have not’ I did define the hierarchy: ‘(non-simple domain relationships: `artist` > `album` > `song`)’, so again I think you misread my question.

Comment: @Maggyero.  All this argument is not appropriate in Comments.  I have already opened a [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233254/discussion-between-performancedba-and-maggyero) from your argumentation in the other question.  Please use it.

Answer (score 0):

Let us take a few instances of my first normal form (1NF) relation schemas variant 1:

```
artist (artist_id, artist_name)
KEY(artist_id)
1 Queen
2 Pink Floyd

album (artist_id, album_id, album_title, album_date)
KEY(artist_id, album_id)
1 1 A Night at the Opera 1975
1 2 News of the World 1977
2 1 The Dark Side of the Moon 1973

song (artist_id, album_id, song_id, song_title)
KEY(artist_id, album_id, song_id)
1 1 1 Love of My Life
1 1 2 Bohemian Rhapsody
1 2 1 We Are the Champions
2 1 1 Time
2 1 2 Money
```

Everybody in this post claims that the previous relation schemas prevent many-to-many relations and are not normalized beyond 1NF and therefore promote data duplication, while their ‘associative’ relations schemas do not have these issues:

```
artist (artist_id, artist_name)
KEY(artist_id)
1 Queen
2 Pink Floyd

album (album_id, album_title, album_date)
KEY(album_id)
1 A Night at the Opera 1975
2 News of the World 1977
3 The Dark Side of the Moon 1973

song (song_id, song_title)
KEY(song_id)
1 Love of My Life
2 Bohemian Rhapsody
3 We Are the Champions
4 Time
5 Money

artist-album (artist_id, album_id)
KEY(artist_id, album_id)
1 1
1 2
2 3

album-song (album_id, song_id)
KEY(album_id, song_id)
1 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
3 5
```

But as I understand it, both my relation schemas and their relation schemas allow many-to-many relations and are normalized in domain–key normal form (DKNF) since their domain dependencies and key dependencies logically imply their constraints, as the only constraints are key dependencies, and therefore prevent data duplication. However their relation schemas have two extra schemas and therefore more data, for no apparent benefit.

Comment: In the first example, you repeat the artist per song even though the artist is given by the album. This means you can have inconsistent data, e.g. `2 1 2 Bohemian Rhapsody` would indicate that the song is by Pink Floyd despite the album is by Queen. This is the kind of "anomaly" normalization is supposed to prevent.

Comment: @JacquesB No in the first example the artist is actually not given by the album because two artists can have an album with the same attributes, in the same way that in Codd’s example an employee is not given by a child because two employees can have a child with the same attributes. In other words, the keys of an album and a song are *local* keys, that is unique in the namespace of an artist; they are not *global* keys.

Comment: DKNF is not relevant to 1NF or normalization to higher NFs from 1NF to 5NF & 6NF (lossless decomposition to components that natural join to an original). "data duplication" doesn't mean anything in particular; normalization to higher NFs improves designs in a way that can reasonably described as reducing duplication. Your use of these terms is neither clear nor sound. (And 1NF-normalizing a nested relation variable is not a way to get good designs. Nor is following a 50-yr-old seminal paper.) Again, suggest you follow a (good) textbook.

Comment: You have misinterpreted what Codd (poorly) said. Codd's "unnormalized" list of name-attributes pairs is NOT a set of relation variables. Each of your "unnormalized" name-attributes lists if taken as a set of relation variables--which you & others have--do NOT 1NF-normalize to the "1NF" designs you give. Rather, Codd's & your "1NF" designs are the 1NF of certain designs with attribute values RELATED IN A CERTAIN WAY to the "unnormalized" list of name-attributes pairs. Please edit your question per my comments. "I have applied this normalization procedure"--No; you have the wrong starting point.

Comment: @Maggyero: OK so album ID is only unique per artist, not across all albums. This means you can't have more than one artist on the same album (in the first example), since a different (artist_Id, album_Id) combination would represent a different album. But you can have multiple artist per album in the second example. This is not a question of normalization though, it is a question if you want your data model to allow multiple artists per album.

Comment: @Maggyero: OK I think I see the issue now. You misunderstand what many-to-many means. Many-to-many means that one element in table A can be associated with multiple elements in table B and vice versa. Lets say Queen and Pink Floyd collaborated on an album - how would you represent that in the first example schema?

Comment: @JacquesB I answered you in the comments of your answer. I would replace the tuple `2 1 The Dark Side of the Moon 1973` with the tuples `1 3 The Dark Side of the Moon 1973` and `2 3 The Dark Side of the Moon 1973`.

Comment: @Maggyero: This shows the table is not normalized since you are repeating title and year. This is because the attributes album_title and album_date only depends on part of the key (album_id but not artist_id).

Comment: @JacquesB Interesting remark, so you mean that it violates 2NF?

Comment: @Maggyero: Yes exactly.

Comment: @JacquesB I don’t think so because a functional dependency *always* applies, i.e. for *all* the instance relations of a relation schema, and for *all* their tuples. Here our relation *schema* `children` does not define a functional dependency `{album_id}` → `{album_title}` nor `{album_id}` → `{album_date}` (it just happens that for *this* instance relation and *these* tuples that they share the same `album_title` and `album_date` values), so there is no partial functional dependency on the key `{artist_id, album_id}`, so 2NF is *not* violated.

Comment: @Maggyero: The confusion is around album_id. You state that album_id is only unique per artist, not across all albums. In that case there is no way to represent that two artists collaborate on the same album, as opposed to two artists releasing different albums which just happen to have to same title. So *either* the data model does not support many-to-many relationships between artist and album, *or* you have a 2NF violation.

Comment: @JacquesB Yes the model does not allow such a distinction, like Codd’s model does not distinguish between two employees with the same child and two employees with different children with the same name. *Both* interpretations are possible. That does not mean that the model does not support many-to-many relationships, because if it was the case, by definition having two tuples `(1, 3, The Dark Side of the Moon, 1973)` and `(2, 3, The Dark Side of the Moon, 1973)` would be prohibited.

Comment: @JacquesB Nor does it mean that there is a 2NF violation, because if it was the case having two tuples `(1, 1, A Night at the Opera, 1975)` and `(2, 1, The Dark Side of the Moon, 1973)` would be prohibited.

Comment: @Maggyero: In that case there is no 2NF violation, agreed, but this also means you *don't* have a many-to-many relationship between albums and artists. A many-to-many would mean that one album (one row in the albums table) could refer to multiple artists (multiple rows in the artists table) through keys - and vice versa. In your example a single row in the albums table cannot refer to multiple artists.

Comment: @philipxy I have finally opened two more focused and precise questions [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/292677/87954) and [there](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/293822/87954).

Comment: @philipxy There is a bounty expiring in 18 hours in the second post.

Comment: My 1st comment on these related Qs & this A included 'What is your 1 question exactly?' & 'Re "is this
right", show all steps of your work with clear justification per given definitions etc. Re good design, including addressing the sort of thing addressed by what the paper calls "normalization", follow a good modern textbook on information modeling & DB design. Ask re where you
are 1st stuck.' You still haven't. Almost every line in that Q involves a misconception. I don't want to (re)write a textbook debunking it when you should follow a textbook in the 1st place. That Q should be closed.

Comment: @philipxy [This specific question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/293822/87954) has all the steps detailed. Can you answer it?

Comment: My last comment was about that post.

Comment: @philipxy ‘Almost every line in that Q involves a misconception’ That does not help me much. Can you provide an example of what I did wrong if this is so obvious? ‘follow a good modern textbook on information modeling & DB design’ Again that does not help me much. Which textbook is better than Fagin’s original paper which introduces 4NF and provides a 4NF normalisation example according to you (I normalised to 5NF here but the procedure is the same)?